# Python: pair a single element with every element in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

For example:
`myStr = 'z'` is to be paired with `myList = ['a','b','c']` so that the output is as follows:

```
['z','a']
['z','b']
['z','c']
```

A one-liner would be great!

I tried to do this:

```
print zip([myStr, x] for x in myList)
```

But the output was not quite as I wanted, as in here:

```
[(['z', 'a'],), (['z', 'b'],), (['z', 'c'],)]
```

Comment: Perhaps `[[myStr, x] for x in myList]`?

Comment: Remove the `zip` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
myList = ['a','b','c']
myStr = 'z'
res = [[myStr, x] for x in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

With [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip):

```
>>> zip(myStr*3,myList)
[('z', 'a'), ('z', 'b'), ('z', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Itertools-[izip-longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
>>>from itertools import izip_longest
>>>[list(i) for i  in list(izip_longest(['z'],['a','b','c'],fillvalue ='z'))]
>>>[['z', 'a'], ['z', 'b'], ['z', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
list(izip_longest([], ['a','b','c'], fillvalue='z'))
```